# Something's wrong with entity-escaping in tag wiki excerpts

Tags: bug, tag-wiki-excerpt, html-entities

Observe [the tag wiki for the infinite-stratos tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/infinite-stratos/info) at Anime.SE. As of now, the excerpt reads:

[image: infinite-stratos tag wiki excerpt]

If you try to [edit the tag wiki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/214), you'll see that the angle brackets there are literal angle brackets `<` and `>`, not HTML entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`:

```
IS <Infinite Stratos> is a light novel series by Izuru Yumizuru with illustrations by Okiura and CHOCO.
```

The angle brackets are also displayed correctly in the hover-popup:

[image: hover popup for infinite-stratos tag]

*However*, if you go to the [tagged questions page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-stratos) for the infinite-stratos tag, the text `<Infinite Stratos>` is missing, presumably eaten by some sort of HTML processor.

[image: /questions/tagged/infinite-stratos]

Looking at the page source suggests that the problem lies somewhere upstream - the `<p>` tag that contains the excerpt text contains the following, without the angle brackets or their contents.

```
IS  is a light novel series by Izuru Yumizuru with illustrations by Okiura and CHOCO.
```

---

Changing the literal angle brackets to entities isn't a fix for this problem - if you do that, then the tag wiki displays the entities literally as `&lt;` and `&gt;` without converting them to `<` and `>`.

Comment: The same bug on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281322/